# making replacements when patterns don't match exactly

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching

I want to simplified some mathematical expressions, and they are similar to 
`FullForm[expr] = Times[Power[d,2],M,Power[\[Kappa],2],Power[Plus[1,Times[Plus[-1,d],\[Kappa]]],-3],H[1][\[Xi],T],Derivative[1,0][H[1]][\[Xi],T]]`.

Suppose `Kc^2=d*M*kappa/(1+(d-1)*kappa)^2`, and `H[1][xi,T] = Q[t]*Cos[\xi]`, then I can further simplify `expr` into `-Kc^2*d*kappa*Q^2*Sin[xi]*Cos[xi]/(1+(d-1)*kappa)`. My question is: how can I make those replacements when sometimes the patterns don't exactly match (e.g. the denominator is not to the power of 2).

Comment: Like this: `Evaluate[expr /. {H[1][\[Xi], T] -> Q[t] Cos[\[Xi]], M -> ((1 - kappa + d kappa)^2 Kc^2)/(d kappa)}] // Simplify`.

Comment: @Alx That's what I've tried for the `Kc` substitution, but I'm wondering if there's a more general approach as in my actual calculations I won't know what I get before hand. For `H[1]`, it fails to evaluate its derivative if I use the above.

Comment: It works for me. First define you `H`: `H[1][\[Xi]_, T_] := Q[T] Cos[\[Xi]]`, then evaluate `expr`, that will give: `-((d^2 M \[Kappa]^2 Cos[\[Xi]] Q[T]^2 Sin[\[Xi]])/(1 + (-1 + d) \[Kappa])^3)`. As for `Kc` I have no more ideas as only make direct subctitution.